# Unable to open magento 1.9 admin panel

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Till yesterday I was able to access my magento 1.9 admin panel.

Today suddenly when i tried accessing the url localhost:7000/manager it started throwing error as

Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Observer.php on line 45.

Please find error in screenshot attached
[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYEQE.png)